# Freeze hovered tooltips to copy their texts

Tags: html, css

I am trying to prepare a more complete enduser help manual for Fabrik (Joomla extension from Fabrikar). I begin by to copy and list all the settings' labels and options on the back end navigation tree.

I helped myself disabling css with Chrome (v. 47) Web Developer extension (v.  0.4.6) on OS X 10.7.5. But I can't succeed in selecting the numerous and fully documented tooltips that show up on hovering.

I have tried to set DevTools extension to "Force element state :hover". The idea was to freeze the tooltip allowing me to select its text. But this doesn't help because the tooltip collapses too soon. Actually, afaik, it is more a matter of javascript.

Here is an example of code and appearence. As much as possible, I would prefer to copy plain text on the rendered html window rather than the code.
Any idea?
Thank you.

```
<div class="control-group">
<div class="control-label">
<label id="jform_params_list_detail_link_target-lbl" 
for="jform_params_list_detail_link_target" class="hasTooltip" title="" 
data-original-title="<strong>Detail Link Target</strong><br />
Target for detail view link, default to opening in the same tab (_self). 
Ignored if AJAX-ified links." aria-invalid="false">
Detail Link Target</label>  </div>
<div class="controls">
<select id="jform_params_list_detail_link_target" name="jform[params]
[list_detail_link_target]" size="4" aria-invalid="false">
<option value="_self">Self</option>
<option value="_blank">Blank (new tab / window)</option>
<option value="_parent">Parent</option>
<option value="_top">Top</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
```

[Screen capture with tooltip display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYwhH.png)

Comment: Not only does a tooltip collapse too soon, but I think it doesn't allow selecting at all. The built-in tooltips are not JavaScript at all.

Comment: Is the tooltip just the data-original-title value in the label? If so, you may be able to add a little javascript to render those data values adjacent to their respective elements.

Comment: Note: I updated my example to use your own code. It is untested, but should give you an idea how to continue.

Comment: Than you @gibberish and others. I feel confuse because for me this topic  is outdated. Should I do something to close it or mark it as answered even if I didn't tried your solution gibberish ? Or else ?

Answer (score 0):

You might wish to use GreaseMonkey -- it's a Firefox extension that runs on the page locally, and allows you (on your side) to manipulate the DOM.

You can also load jQuery with it, and use some pretty cool javascript to automate what you are trying to do.

To use it, install the [GreaseMonkey add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/), restart Firefox, and navigate to the page.

Then, on the toolbar, click the GreaseMonkey button and choose New User Script. Just add the domain (e.g. `yoursitename.com`)to the top three fields, and click OK.

Next, modify the script so it looks something like this:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        mysite.com
// @namespace   mysite.com
// @description mysite.com
// @include     http://*.mysite.*/*
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

$(function(){

    //jQuery goes here, for example:
    $('.control-label label').each(function(){
        var cls = $(this).attr('class');
        if (cls=='hasTooltip'){
            alert( $(this).attr('data-original-title');
        }
    });

});
```