# hide a div on a website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I know to hide a div on a website if I have the source control. I can set div display to none or call javascript hide() on the div id. But how can I permanently remove a div from a website for which I don't have a source control. Just for my rendering, if I load or refresh the page, I should see that div gone. Are there any basic work around or hacks for that? I don't want to inspect and set display none for div every time I refresh the website.

Comment: You can use [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) for Firefox or [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en) for Chrome. Both allow you to modify the look of a website locally.

Comment: Note again that Greasemonkey / Tampermonkey only remove the div on your own computer, no one else's. It is not possible to remove from other machines without source control. I suspect you already know this, but wanted to be clear.  See [this post re using Greasemonkey](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34801636)

Comment: @ArcaneCraeda Please add your comment as an answer for an upvote, since you were clearly first to respond by a considerable period.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en) for Chrome

or [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) for Firefox

Comment: If it's just for your rendering this should work. Obviously, you can't control a website's content that you don't have access to.

Answer (score 0):

You might use a (somewhat weird :) construct: build your own HTML document, containing only:

- an `<iframe src="---your external page--->"`
- a `<script>` where you explicitly add `style="display: none;"` to all elements where you need it

Answer (score -1):

Browser (Chrome in my example) extensions has needed functionality.
You can use [Custom JavaScript for websites](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/custom-javascript-for-web/poakhlngfciodnhlhhgnaaelnpjljija) extension, and configure additional code execution for every page reload without opening DevTools.